# Is using a 3200MHz DDR4 Memory O.C.?

Tags: memory, motherboard, overclocking

I was selecting the parts for a new Server when i read in the specifications of the motherboard ([Gigabyte Z170 Gaming 5](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5498#ov)) this:

> Support for DDR4 3466(O.C.) /3400(O.C.) /3333(O.C.) /3300(O.C.) /3200(O.C.) /3000(O.C.) /2800(O.C.) /2666(O.C.) /2400(O.C.) /2133 MHz memory modules

Since the RAM i selected is a Corsair Vengance Lpx DDR4 8GB 3200mhz (two cards) i was wondering if this counts as OC for this motherboard and if its safe to install them.

I was also wondering if there would be much difference with 2133 modules? The server will be running a program that copies files to ram, process them and copies them back to disk.

I'm also buying an Intel I7 6700.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the motherboard natively supports RAM @ 2133MHz, and if you mount a higher speed RAM (@ 3466, 3400, 3333, 3300, 3200, 3000, 2800, 2666, 2400MHz) that motherboard will still run it @ 2133MHz. **However**, in this case, you can overclock it to use it at full speed.

For example, mounting your 3200MHz RAM would mean that it will still run @ 2133MHz, unless you decide to overclock it up to 3200MHz.

It is safe to overclock your RAM to that speed if it natively supports it (which is your case), although the best thing you could do is to run some benchmarks and test the performance of your server when the RAM is OCd and not, to see if it's worth it. Also remember that overclocking the RAM will result in higher CPU temperatures, so check on them and be sure to have a proper cooling system.

Comment: Got it!, its safe to do so for server aplications?

Comment: @Arheisel Edited.